# How to rearrange layed out JPanels in a JPanel via drag

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel, mouse-listeners

I have a very simple example. I'm trying to get working before i try and apply this to the more complex program I have planned. But I'm trying to be able to drag and drop the JPanels that are in say a Flow or Vertical Layout.

I'm not really sure where to start, as this isn't really anything I've dealt with before. But from what I've researched, it would seem that I surely need a listener on each JPanel, that listens for clicks. From here it will gather initial data from a mousePressed, and run a overridden `repaint()`, that will update the coordinates of the panel in the container. Then according to where the coordinate is placed, it will repack() and hopefully resize the panels.

Am I onto the right track?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;


public class DraggablePanels extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Border raisedbevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
    int px, py;
    JPanel main = new JPanel();

    public DraggablePanels(){
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                px = e.getX();
                py = e.getY();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        p1.setBorder(raisedbevel);
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();

        p2.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                px = e.getX();
                py = e.getY();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        p2.setBorder(raisedbevel);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Thing 1"));
        p2.add(new JLabel("Thing 2"));

        main.add(p1);
        main.add(p2);

        add(main);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        DraggablePanels d = new DraggablePanels();
    }

}
```

Comment: *"I have a very simple example."*  What you are trying to do is not simple. *"But I'm trying to be able to drag and drop the JPanels that are in say a Flow or Vertical Layout."*  Consider using a `JList`, which is better suited to handling D-n-D rearrangement of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Sample Application for rearranging jpanel:

http://www.bryanesmith.com/docs/drag-and-drop-java-5/